# AuthoHotKey exclusive double tap shift followed by action key

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to complete an autohotkey script where you can double tap any SHIFT key twice and follow it by a certain letter to activate a macro.
I have the following script but i have two "bugs" i can't figure out how to solve. I've tried other forums with no luck. Hoping someone can help me out.
I'm a little new at this.

Bug 1:  The macro is activated if you press any letter in between the two SHIFTs where it should only be activated if you press the SHIFTs exclusively. For example, pressing SHIFT, s, SHIFT, d will enable the macro.

Bug 2:  I'm not sure how this happens but with the following code, I periodically get all or some of the macros to activate while i'm typing. It seems to happen when I type the first capital letter in a sentence. But only sometimes. For example... "bla bla bla profiles. S"

I've fooled around with the timeouts but that doesn't seem to make much of a difference. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Jeff.

```
~Shift Up::
If (A_ThisHotkey == A_PriorHotkey && A_TimeSincePriorHotkey < 400)
{
    Double_SHIFT := true
    Sleep, 2000
    Double_SHIFT := false
}
return

; Press a key within two seconds after double tapping the Shift key, to activate an action:
#If (Double_SHIFT)
    d::
    FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,,MM/dd/yy - hh:mmtt
    SendInput %CurrentDateTime%
            Double_SHIFT :=false
            return
    a:: MsgBox, Test
    s:: MsgBox, Test
    f:: MsgBox, Test
return
```

Comment: I can't recreate the 2nd issue.

Comment: Thanks so much. i'm going to test this for a while. The fix may take care of the 2nd issue. Will let you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix for Bug 1:

```
endKeys := "{BS}{Enter}{Insert}{Home}{Pgup}{PdDwn}End}{Delete}" 
     . "{F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}"
     . "{LShift}{RShift}{Tab}{Esc}{CAPSLOCK}{Ctrl}{PrintScreen}{NumLock}" 
     . "{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}{Numpad0}" 
     . "{Numpad7}{Numpad8}{Numpad9}{NumpadDel}{Up}{Down}{Left}{Right}"
     . "{LAlt}{RAlt}{.}{,}{/}"

~Alt Up::
    Input, key, V L1 t0.5 E, % endKeys
    If (Errorlevel ~= "Alt") {
        Double_ALT := true
        Sleep 2000
        Double_ALT := false
    }
return

; Press a key within two seconds after double tapping the Alt key, to activate an action:
#If (Double_ALT)
    d::
    FormatTime, CurrentDateTime,,MM/dd/yy - hh:mmtt
    SendInput %CurrentDateTime%
            Double_ALT :=false
            return
    a:: MsgBox, Test
    s:: MsgBox, Test
    f:: MsgBox, Test
return
```

Comment: Awsome. I'll test this out but this seems to work. Thanks! It may fix bug 2 as well. So "% endKeys means if any of the listed keys are typed in between, it cancels? I tested typing a period in between and that doesn't activate either but a period is not included. Just curious why you didn't include one in the endKeys. Thanks again!

Comment: Missed one or a few, add em in. If the answer works, please accept it, so that others will know.

Comment: I'm still getting bug 2. It happens when i type the first capital letter of a sentence and only happens very infrequently. Very hard to reproduce on demand. Is the "endKeys" a list of keys that cancel the marco if the key is typed in between Shifts? If so wouldn't the {LShift} and {RShift} kill the marco? I thought adding {Space} and {.} would help but didn't. while writing this i just got it to happen a few times as I was typing "adding {S..." then the macro activated when i typed "p", "a", "c", and "e". still hard to reproduce but maybe that helps. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is caused by an accidental double shift or "bounce" while typing very fast. I'm going to propose to my boss to use Alt.

Comment: Yes the EndKeys are a list of keys that cancel the Input command. It's possible also that your keyboard is the  culprit. Try swapping it with a differnet model. If you can get a mechanical keyboard.

Comment: You're right. It happens with most laptops and some manual keyboards. I've decided to try abandon Shift and use a double tap "Alt" instead to avoid the frequent use of Shift. I've tried replacing your code with Alt but could not get it to work. Could you show how to use your code with Alt instead? And as always, thanks for your input and help.

Comment: Edited with the changes.

Comment: And once again. Thanks! You're the best!

Comment: I'd like to revisit this and hope you can help with one more issue. When you press a "trigger" letter like "d" it actually types the "d". Is there any way to get it to not type d when you use it in combination with the ALT ALT macro?